# What are the benefits to using iframes for ajax long polling?

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet, long-polling

What are the benefits of using iframes for Comet long polling?  Why not just keep an asynchronous ajax request in a script file pulled into the main page?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes portability to IE possible:
http://softwareas.com/portable-comet-its-the-iframe-stupid

Also, some people use it as a security feature. Within an iFrame you can enclose everything within a JavaScript closure and improve your security. There are better ideas for security though.

- http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/
- http://www.adsafe.org/

Comment: Thanks.  So are iframes a requirement to get ajax to work with IE?

Comment: Apparently iframes are a requirement to get Comet Ajax to work with IE.  I can't say for sure, because I've never tried it without an iframe.